# What is the actual meaning of Gayathri mantra?

Tags: mantras, gayatri-mantra

I have been chanting that mantra every morning to today and don't have a clue of what it means.

But I realize that the sound produced while chanting that mantra is the most important part; I still want to know its meaning.

Comment: Sanskrit language is a complete language and all other languages are incomplete that is why we cannot describe exact translation of sanskrit verses in English,hindi or anyother language

Comment: @Creator What do you mean by complete vs. incomplete?  What properties of "completeness" does Sanskrit have that, say, Latin does not?

Comment: Your question already has an answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/463/81

Comment: btw, as a side note to my answer below, when receiving sannyas initiation, a person is given a different gayatri for sadhus to chant every day. Sorry, don't ask what it is, not allowed.

Comment: One of the meaning: Om, the blissful Mother, substance and substrate of the Three worlds, we meditate on Thee, and it is Thee who illumines our Mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gayatri is Rig veda (III. lxii. 10.) Ralph Griffith's translation is

> May we attain that excellent glory of Savitar the God :
>   So May he stimulate our prayers.

A better translation might be :

> We meditate on the glory of that Being who has produced this universe.
>   May He enlighten our minds

Answer (score 0):

The [mantra meaning](http://insightstate.com/):

"O thou existence Absolute, Creator of the three dimensions, we contemplate upon thy divine light. May He stimulate our intellect and bestow upon us true knowledge."

Or simply,

"O Divine mother, our hearts are filled with darkness. Please make this darkness distant from us and promote illumination within us."

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! Can you pls. Specifically point to the link where this meaning is given.

Answer (score -1):

> The word "Gayatri" itself explains the reason for the existence of
>   this mantra. It has its origin in the Sanskrit phrase Gayantam Triyate
>   iti, and refers to that mantra which rescues the chanter from all
>   adverse situations that may lead to mortality.
>
> Goddess Gayatri is also called "Veda-Mata" or the Mother of the Vedas
>   - Rig, Yajur, Saam and Atharva - because it is the very basis of the Vedas. It is the basis, the reality behind the experienced and the
>   cognized universe.
>
> [Source](http://hinduism.about.com/od/prayersmantras/a/The-Gayatri-Mantra.htm)

Aum

Bhuh Bhuvah Svah

Tat Savitur Varenyam

Bhargo Devasya Dheemahi

Dhiyo Yo nah Prachodayat

[image]