# Metrical restoration of Gayatri Mantra

Tags: vedas, gayatri-mantra

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gayatri_Mantra#Text) that a metrically restored version of Gayatri Mantra would have "váreṇiyam" instead of "vareṇyaṃ" i.e,

> tát savitúr váreṇiyam
>      bhárgo devásya dhīmahi
>   dhíyo yó naḥ pracodáyāt

Has it ever been chanted with "váreṇiyam" instead of "vareṇyaṃ" anytime in ancient rituals?

Comment: Not only ancient times, it is varenium always. Gayatri is a mantra which has 24 letters.If we say it as varenyam, it will become 23 only. So we should always say Vareniyam. I read that   in Chandogyopanishad also it is vareniyam only.

Comment: @SreeCharan Then where does the version containing váreṇiyam come from?

Comment: @@Ishan Singh..In Veda Samhitas Varenyam is only present..So no need to look any further.

Comment: fyi, mantras are not supposed to be discussed publicly.. they should be passed down from guru to shishya. Gayatri mantra should only be chanted if upanayanam was done and you wear yagnopaveetam and  do sandhya. mantras need to be respected and hidden for them to have effect and more importantly, to avoid adverse effects.

Comment: @ram Yes, but ill pronunciation of mantras can have much adverse effects and render them ineffective. In order to establish a Vedic society, things need to be brought in limelight to avoid distortion of the sacred knowledge, as intended by Maharishis.

Comment: There are mantras which should be taken through Upadesam only. Gayatri mantra is one of them. If you are going to give mantram to anyone, find the eligible one. This is a public site and no one knows who sees these site. If someone ineligible is going to use it, you will be responsible for that result. It should be a guru who should give gayatri manta(father in all cases). Vareniyam is not an ill pronunciation. Singing mantras and keeping them as ringtones is ill pronunciation **Who performs sanshyavandanam daily would know that. No  need of a post on site.**  Which transliteration did you use

Comment: While writing vareniyam, you used Transliteration or tone used for Gayatri? Because used IAST transliteration for Varenyam. This creates confusion.

Comment: IN sama veda, it is said as Vareniyam and in other vedas it is Varenyam. To justify the chandas, it is said as vareniyam.

Comment: @IshanSingh, yes i agree with you, but figuring out the correct pronunciation should not be discussed publicly, it should only be done from guru who did brahmopadesam, or father, or a spiritual leader like in mutts or ashrams.

Comment: @ram I hold the Vedic view in this regard than the medieval view which led to the decline of Indian civilization. This is one of the reasons why despite being much superior to Greek Philosophy, Indian Philosophy isn't widespread.

Comment: @SreeCharan Gayatri Mantra has been chanted for a long time as Varenyam in North India so there must be a reason why have we been doing that, given that Vedas were realized on the banks of Saraswati River. I know the proper procedure for chanting Mantras. It's no good to keep it in secret chambers and later blame others for mispronunciation, this practice is likely a later corruption due to invading forces. Maharishis never intended it to be this way.

Comment: *"Vedas were realized on the banks of Saraswati River"* - what do you mean by realized? Vedas are eternal. *"It's no good to keep it in secret chambers and later blame others for mispronunciation"* - do you also believe machine guns and nuclear codes should be given to everyone, rather than just a qualified few? Just as weapons, which are powerful, are kept in secret by a select few, to maintain peace in the world.. mantras, which are powerful, are kept in secret by a select few, to maintain peace in the world. The problem now is that those select few stopped chanting them & spread it to all.

Comment: @ram That's why I wrote realized and not written.

Comment: they were realized (by mantra drashta, or rishis) long back - the Vedas were one big clump of mantras until Vyasa's avatara - all he did was divided/categorized them. Like splitting a big book into 4 chapters.

Comment: @ram When did I say Vyasa realized them? They were realized by Sapta Rishis on the banks of river Saraswati.

Comment: Also please note that wikipedia is maintained by normal people like you and me ( may be more knowledgeable )  . It doesn't exists on it's own.

Answer (score 5):

The Gayatri Mantra that is present in the Veda Samhitas has **Varenyam** in it and not Vareniyam.

The Gayatri mantra of Viswamitra Gatinah is not in the Gayatri metre but in a slightly variant metre called the Nichruth Gaytari which is made of 23 syllables and not of 24 syllables.

It is found in Rig Veda 3.62.10, [Taittiriya Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taittiriya_Shakha) 1.5.6.12 of Krishna Yajur Veda  and in [Vajasaneyi Samhita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yajurveda) 3.35 of the Shukla Yajurveda. And in all these versions **varenyam is only present**.

> tat savitur varenyam

All throughout North India varenyam is chanted. Probably they pronounce it as vareniyam in the South only.

The same Mantra is present in the Yajur Veda ( Vajasaneyi Samhita 36.3, Krishna Yajur Veda Taiitiriya Samhita 4.1.11.1 ) as well, but there the additional words are present viz

> bhur bhuvah svah

thus changing the chandah (metre) to Ushnik from Nichruth Gayatri. Ushnik has 27 syllables.

I don't know how vareniyum came into being though. Probably something to do with Veda  Shakhas ( ? ). For example, the persons belonging to Krishna Yajur Veda indeed replace the word Svah by Suvaha in the Mantra.

### Abbreviations used in the answer :

**Rig Veda 3.62.10** - Mantra 10 of Sukta 62 of Mandala 3 of Rig Veda Samhita.

**Taittiriya Samhita 1.5.6.2** - Verse 2 in Anuvaka 6 in Prapathaka 5 of Kanda 1 of that Samhita.

**Vajasaneyi Samhita 3.35** - Mantra 35 of Adhyaya 3 of that Samhita.

**EDIT**

Another confusion which must be cleared is that Gayatri metre have to have 24 syllables. **This is completely wrong. Gayatri is a name of a family of metres.**

The number of syllables can vary from 26 to 19. **The Gayatri metre has as many as 10 variants.**. The Nichruth Gayatri is one such variant.

Apart from differences in the number of syllables, more variants occur due to the padas. Some variants of Gayatri have 5 padas.

Some of them have formations such as :

5|5|5|5|6, 5|5|5|4|6, 6|7|11, 7|7|7|, 7|6|6 etc and all of them belong to the Gayatri family of metre.

The Gayatri mantra that appears in RV 3.62.10 is having 23 syllables. Even in the classical reference, Katyayana's Anukramanika, **Katyayana calls the 23-syllabled metre by the name Gayatri only.**

Similarly, all the other major Vedic meters are having more than one variants. For example, Anushtup is having 11 variants. Brihati is having 11 variants and the Trishtup chandaha has as many as 14 variants.

Comment: similar thing i have posted ..

Comment: @ Ok..but adhikantu NA doshAya..:D

Comment: The only mantra present in all the vedas is this alone. In Chandogyopanishad, it is Vareniyam. 24 syllables. In  the other vedas, it is varenyam.

Comment: @SreeCharan I am talking about Veda Samhitas..nothing is more authoritative than Veda Samhitas..And wherever this mantra appears in the Samhitas varenyam is used... so, without any iota of doubt varenyam is correct..

Comment: It will be in some part of Samavedam. Check in Sama vedam again. I didn't check . I read that in Chandogyopanishad, it is vareniyam.   You can't say version is only correct. Thant's not right. Why do people chant Vareniyam if they know it is wrong? There will be vareiyam in Samavedam. Check if you want clarification.

Answer (score 3):

His holiness, late Shankaracharya Swamiji of Sringeri Peetam, Sri Abhinava Vidhya Teertha Swamiji clarifies this point in his book "Sandhyavandhanam". Gayathri has only 23 letters. The word Varenyam should be considered as Vareniyam then it becomes 24, but it should not be spelled as vareniyam during japa.

It should always be spelled as Varenyam. He clarifies his point by quoting from the vedas. A must read book for who chant Gayathri.

Comment: It would be better if you can quote the clarification made by Swamiji from Sandhyavandanam.

Comment: He cites the Saura Ashtakshara mantra which has only 7 syllables but it is considered as ashtakshara (having 8 syllables),

घृणिरिति द्वे अक्षरे ! सूर्य इति त्रीणि ! आदित्य इति त्रीणि ! ( तैत्रीय ब्राह्मण )

Gruni (घृणि) should be considered as having 2 syllables, Soorya (सूर्य) should be considered as having 3 syllables and Aditya (आदित्य) should be considered as having 3 syllables.

Going by the same logic we should consider Varenyam as Vareniyam (not to be spelled as Vareniyam)

When we have a confusion just blindly follow the authority. It's all too complicated subject for us :-)

Comment: Yes, [edit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/28356/edit) the answer to include it.

Answer (score 2):

It is chanted in both ways. As far as I know, it appears in the Samhita as "Varenyam" Rig Veda 3.62.10.

But to fit in the meter of 24 letters (gAyatri chhandas) it is chanted as vareniyam by many. However, Vareniyam or Varenyam do not alter its meaning. It is just done for the purpose of maintaining the chhandas.

North Indians mostly chant it as Varenyam. Some people say that it comes under Nichrud gAyatri chhandas.

South Indians prefer to chant as Vareniyam. Still meaning and potency is not altered.

Even the vyahriti is chanted as "suvah:" by some south Indians and as "svah:" by north Indians.

Comment: It is not the regional difference.It is due to difference in Veda Shakhas. In Samaveda, it is vareniyam. In other vedas, it is varenyam. Suva is the name of a loka. The vyahritis are name after the lokas or may be viceversa.

Comment: @SreeCharan what is difference between Suvah and Svah