# How can we easily identify the 'meter' in vedic scriptures?

Tags: vedas, vedic-chanting

Most would be familiar with the vedic meter system of gayathri, usnih, anushtubh etc. Apart from just saying that the difference is in number of syllables or lines, is there an easy way how we can recognize which meter a certain work is set in to?

Comment: Are u looking for metrical information given in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17792/4732) for the meters u hv mentioned?

Comment: @Rickross Hmm. it may be related... my question is more on how to we easily identify the meter when we hear some mantras get recited. I understand this might be more of a technical question.

Answer (score 1):

It is given at the top of each mantra.