# What are the 21 meters known to Rig Vedic seers?

Tags: rig-veda

The known [major Vedic meters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedic_meter#Overview) are:

Gāyatrī, Uṣṇih, Anuṣṭubh, Bṛhatī, Pankti, Triṣṭubh and Jagatī

Rig Veda [IV.1.16](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04001.htm) narrates 21 meters/chandas, as known to the seers of Rig Veda.

> The Milch-cow's earliest name they comprehended: they found the
>   Mother's ***thrice-seven noblest titles***. This the bands knew, and sent
>   forth acclamation:with the Bull's sheen the Red One was apparent.

Can anyone quote the remaining Vedic meters?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/37884/277

Comment: @Paṇḍyā: Thanks for doing extensive research and posting an answer, albeit under different question.    My intentions are clear.  I want this site to become a learning room for all.  Some members may be taking my questions/answers as provoking.  Still some times I am getting very good responses like yours. Anyways, thanks once again.