# Why is there a gayatri mantra for every mantra?

Tags: mantras, gayatri-mantra, gayatri

Hello so when I look up any God or Goddess mantra there is always a Gayatri mantra for them for example I search Ganesha mantra and there is also Ganesh Gayatri mantra, Shiva mantra and Shiva Gayatri mantra, Kamadev and Kamadev Gayatri mantra and they all have the same suffixes of the Gayatri mantra. So I ask why is there a Gayatri version of every single mantra for a God or Goddess out there? How is the Ganesha Gayatri mantra different from the regular Ganesha mantra? What does the Gayatri do to the mantra? Should I chant the Gayatri versions first instead of the regular ones? Thank you in advance for answering.

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/31667/21353

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/459/21353

Comment: Hi, Welcome to HSE. Kindly visit [How Does a New User Get Started on HSE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-hinduism-se). Have an enriching journey ahead.

Comment: Also, this is an opinion based question, IMO. It's like asking why there's is a sect for each of Śhiva, Viśhňu, Śhakti, etc., when the Supreme Brahman encompasses everything.

Comment: "Gayatri" is actually a metre, not a specific mantra as you are thinking. The different 'gayatris' all have the same metre.

Comment: Metre as in amount of syllables right? So they all have the same words like 'prachodayaat' 'dheemahi' 'vidmahe' etc, what effect does this add to the mantra?

Comment: @QueenScorpio , it adds similar effects as like: "Give me that book" vs "Please, can you lend me that book?"

Comment: Does this change anything in the spirit? Coz if not why are the words there? How is it different from the regular mantra